# How to configure Spring redis sentinel in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce, redis-sentinel

I have a redis sentinel master slave setup with 1 master and 3 slaves and this is in Kubernetes environment.In the spring lettuce configuration, I have to specify the sentinels URLs with port numbers. How should I specify the URL for each sentinel? [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:sentinel) specifies IP and port. In the local it's ok but when in k8s, how should I configure? I installed the set up with [bitnami redis chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis). Below is how it's done locally.

```java
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
    RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = 
        new RedisSentinelConfiguration().master("mymaster")
                                        .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26379)
                                        .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26380);
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing -> using the bitnami helm chart is the right way to do things.

Although a bit of a different implementation, heres how we implemented the same master slave setup AND also avoided the above problem while ensuring the MAXIMUM availability we ever witnessed (less than 2 secs Downtime for master)

- We made two services - one for master and another for slaves.
- a PV PVC that was shared between the slaves and master where ONLY Master would write and slaves would only read from PV
- this way we could always ensure that there was 1 pod running ALL time for master and N replicas behind the headless service for slaves.

In application slaves and master URL's would always be different, thus ensuring a clear "WRITE" and "READ" isolation and improving the stability of system with almost no failures for reads.

Answer (score 0):

Install the helm chart with sentinel enabled

```
helm install my-release bitnami/redis --set sentinel.enabled=true
```

A service with name `my-release-redis` will be created and can be accessed via `my-release-redis.namespacename.svc.cluster.local:26379` from any namespace and from the same namespace it's much simpler using `my-release-redis:26379`

Comment: I know that the service my-reelase-redis is created.But what should i provide in my sentinel()method as parameter.Should i repeat the service name and port for each sentinel pod or just one time?

Comment: You can use the service name once..behind the scenes it will connect to one of the pods

Comment: Thanks for the response.However when i install the chart there will be two services for redis . One is redis and other is redis-headless.My understanding is that i should use the headless-svc as the url parameter.Right?

Comment: So if you look at the helm installation output it says how to access sentinel and I think I saw redis there and not headless